# Debian default PATH value

Tags: linux, bash, path, debian

I am running an interactive non-login shell

```
$ echo $-
himBH

$ shopt login_shell
login_shell     off
```

which means that only `~/.bashrc`
[should be read](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). However even with no PATH in `~/.bashrc`, PATH is still defined

```
$ grep PATH ~/.bashrc | wc
      0       0       0

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Where is this definition coming from?

Comment: there's `rc` files for the shells in `/etc`, usually. they set the system-wide defaults for the shells, which then get overriden/modified by the per-user `rc` files in the user's home directory.

Comment: How are you starting this bash? what is the $PATH inside the login shell from which you are launching this bash?